# Create multiple DNS Route53 A record using Terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-route53, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I have created some AWS EC2 instances using terraform as below:

```
resource "aws_instance" "deploya"{
....
}
resource "aws_instance" "deployb"{
....
}
resource "aws_instance" "deployc"{
....
}
```

For the above aws_instances, I want to create route_53 A record.

I have the names for the A record in locals as below. They are also used at many other places in the script

```
locals {
    namea = "namea.aws.ra.com"
    nameb = "nameb.aws.ra.com"
    namec = "namec.aws.ra.com"
}
```

I know I can create Route53 A record for each aws_instance as below:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "www" {
      allow_overwrite = true
      zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.selected.zone_id
      name    = local.namea
      type    = "A"
      ttl     = "300"
      records = [aws_instance.deploya.private_ip]
    }
```

The issue I am facing in the manual approach above is code length, repetition and maintainability I want to use some iteration here to keep the code compact, which I am not able to figure out being new to Terraform. Also, there could be many more aws_instances.

How can the code be kept compact here?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html) when creating resources:

```
locals {
  instances = {
    namea = "namea.aws.ra.com"
    nameb = "nameb.aws.ra.com"
    namec = "namec.aws.ra.com"
  }
}
resource "aws_route53_record" "www" {
  for_each        = local.instances
  allow_overwrite = true
  zone_id         = data.aws_route53_zone.selected.zone_id
  name            = each.value
  type            = "A"
  ttl             = "300"
  records         = [aws_instance.deploya.private_ip]
}
```

Comment: It's not said explicitly in the question, but I'd guess OP wants deploya.private_ip to use namea, deployb.private_ip to use nameb, etc. So you'd rather have a map a not a list to iterate over with `for_each`

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki I have iterated it over map and got the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question. If someone wants to achieve creating N num of A records for N num of ec2 instances please you can use map to iterate key and value.

```
locals {
  host_names = {
    namea = "namea.aws.ra.com"
    nameb = "nameb.aws.ra.com"
    namec = "namec.aws.ra.com"
  }
  deploy_names = {
    deploya = aws_instance.deploya
    deployb = aws_instance.deployb
    deployc = aws_instance.deployc
  }
  host_deploy_names = zipmap(values(local.host_names),values(local.deploy_names))
}
resource "aws_route53_record" "www" {
  for_each        = local.host_deploy_names
  allow_overwrite = true
  zone_id         = data.aws_route53_zone.selected.zone_id
  name            = each.key
  type            = "A"
  ttl             = "300"
  records         = [each.value.private_ip]
}
```